# Cannot get Assertion error to print to console.log error: ‘class CBigNum’ has no member named ‘SetCompact’

Tags: c++, bash, compiler-errors, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I've been attempting a PIVX clone. I have the Merkle hash (I used [GenesisH0](https://github.com/lhartikk/GenesisH0)) and am having trouble getting the genesis hash (the one from GenesisH0 hasn't worked, as I get a compile time error only for the genesis hash).

Added the below code to get the errors to print to console.log and keep getting a compile error.

~line 200 in src/chainparams.cpp

```
if(genesis.GetHash() != uint256("0x"))
        {
            printf("Searching for genesis block...\n");
            uint256 hashTarget = CBigNum().SetCompact(genesis.nBits).getuint256();
            while(uint256(genesis.GetHash()) > hashTarget)
            {
                ++genesis.nNonce;
                if (genesis.nNonce == 0)
                {
                    printf("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time");
                    std::cout << std::string("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time:\n");
                    ++genesis.nTime;
                }
                if (genesis.nNonce % 10000 == 0)
                {
                    printf("Mainnet: nonce %08u: hash = %s \n", genesis.nNonce, genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
                }
            }
            printf("block.nTime = %u \n", genesis.nTime);
            printf("block.nNonce = %u \n", genesis.nNonce);
            printf("block.GetHash = %s\n", genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
        }
```

This is the compile error I am getting:

```
chainparams.cpp: In constructor ‘CMainParams::CMainParams()’:
chainparams.cpp:203:44: error: ‘class CBigNum’ has no member named ‘SetCompact’
             uint256 hashTarget = CBigNum().SetCompact(genesis.nBits).getuint256();
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I've removed and then reinstalled my openssl dependency with [this](https://github.com/vertcoin-project/vertcoin-core/issues/43#issuecomment-447852235) amongst a handful of other methods.